# Mac bash split cannot split by line-bytes

Tags: bash, macos

I'd like to split a file by bytes while maintaining full lines via

```
split -C <bytes> filename
```

However, the default split doesn't accept `-C`

```
split: illegal option -- C
usage: split [-a sufflen] [-b byte_count] [-l line_count] [-p pattern]
             [file [prefix]]
```

I've `brew install coreutils`, which [looks like it should support what I want](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html).

How do I change split to use coreutils?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`brew install coreutils` will install the commands prefixed with 'g' by default. So `split` should be available if you type `gsplit`.

If you want to use the commands using original names, please add `/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin` to your `$PATH`.

For more information, see https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/ and `brew info coreutils`.

Comment: `--with-default-names` is deprecated, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57180138/3823815

Comment: Thanks @louis_guitton, updated the answer based on your findings.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

```
brew info coreutils
...
==> Caveats
All commands have been installed with the prefix 'g'.
```

So its just `gsplit -C $BYTES filename`

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the path of the file and execute the following command
split -b 500m  inputFile output_files.split.txt

Example

split -b 500m  sample.txt output_files.split.txt

Answer (score 0):

`--with-default-names` was removed from brew, so if you need to run one command with its normal name, you need to add something to your path. See below

```
brew info coreutils
...
==> Caveats
Commands also provided by macOS have been installed with the prefix "g".
If you need to use these commands with their normal names, you
can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:
   PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```